Using @autoclosure in Swift: Can It Behave Like Overloaded Functions?
I have a function that uses @autoclosure. Is there a way to make @autoclosure behave similarly to overloaded functions, so it automatically knows which syntax is right for variables like in my case?
func myEnvironment(_ bindings: @autoclosure () -> [Int], _ body: ([Int]) -> Int) -> Int {
    let vars = bindings()
    return body(vars)
}

// prints 4
let result = myEnvironment([]) { _ in
    2 + 2
}

// Error
// prints 6
let result2 = myEnvironment {
    let x = 1
    let y = 2
    let z = 3
    return [x, y, z]
} _: { vars in
    vars[0] + vars[1] + vars[2]
}


Error
// prints 6
let result2 = myEnvironment {
    let x = 1
    let y = 2
    let z = 3
    return [x, y, z]
} _: { vars in
    vars[0] + vars[1] + vars[2]
}

error 1:
Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored

error 2:
Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to closure result type 'Int'

Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior, or do I need to modify my code?
I saw this post How to use Swift @autoclosure but it did not answer my question. Any suggestions are appreciated.

So you also want the auto closure to sometimes not be “auto”, and allow callers to pass an actual closure to the parameter?

@Sweeper Yes, that's a good way of saying it, sometimes not be auto and sometimes be auto, but kind of automatically figure it out through syntax.

How about just add another overload without @autoclosure?

Good point, overall, if there is no other way of doing it, sure. It would be nice that @autoclosure have that behavior built in.

I assume you want to also allow the caller to pass in a code block that contains multiple lines of code as the autoclosure.
You can declare another overload that does not take an @autoclosure.
// The '@autolcosure' overload can delegate to the new overload:
func myEnvironment(_ bindings: @autoclosure () -> [Int], _ body: ([Int]) -> Int) -> Int {
    myEnvironment(bindings, body)
}

func myEnvironment(_ bindings: () -> [Int], _ body: ([Int]) -> Int) -> Int {
    let vars = bindings()
    return body(vars)
}

// ------------

// or the other way around!
func myEnvironment(_ bindings: () -> [Int], _ body: ([Int]) -> Int) -> Int {
    myEnvironment(bindings(), body)
}

func myEnvironment(_ bindings: @autoclosure () -> [Int], _ body: ([Int]) -> Int) -> Int {
    let vars = bindings()
    return body(vars)
}

If you cannot add overloads for some reason, you can pass an "immediately invoked" closure instead. Because of @autoclosure, this closure isn't actually immediately invoked.
myEnvironment({
    let x = 1
    let y = 2
    let z = 3
    return [x, y, z]
}()) { x in
    vars[0] + vars[1] + vars[2]
}

